# If I created a kernel, how would I create an executable syntax

Tags: syntax, kernel, executable, binaryfiles

I want to create a kernel (Not related to Linux kernel) that runs a process. Linux, MacOS, MS-DOS(Windows), And FreeBSD all have specific executables that each have a unique syntax. for example: all Mach-O binaries have `cffa edfe 0700 0001` in the beginning. If I wanted to create a binary with my kernel, How would I have to configure my kernel to have a specific executable syntax syntax?

Comment: Good start would be to see how Linux does it - just read kernel source code.

Comment: the Linux kernel source is very complicated, I don't even know where to start. I just want to use  2 or 3 assembly files and 1 c file